# Please, I need a more detailed explanation of the particular solution of the problem with vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

Here is the problem and its solution ([link to the source](http://www.bymath.com/studyguide/alg/sec/helpanssol/sol4015.htm) if you are interested):

Two different points $A$ and $B$ are given. Find a set of such points $M$, that $\overrightarrow{MA}\cdot\overrightarrow{MB}=k^2$, where $k$ is a given non-zero number.

**The solution:**

Let coordinates of points be: $A(x_a, y_a), B(x_b, y_b), M(x, y)$.

Then:

$$
\begin{align}
& \overrightarrow{MA}=(x_a - x, y_a - y), \overrightarrow{MB}=(x_b - x, y_b - y), \\ 
& \overrightarrow{MA}\cdot\overrightarrow{MB}= (x_a - x)(x_b - x)+(y_a - y)(y_b - y)=k^2
\end{align}
$$

Transform the last expression, opening brackets:

$$
x_a x_b - (x_a+x_b)x + x^2 + y_a y_b - (y_a+y_b)y + y^2 = k^2
$$

**At this point I ask someone to provide a more detailed explanation, please, cause I failed to understand the next steps.** What a transformation has been made here?

$$
\left( x - \frac{x_a + x_b}{2} \right)^2 - \frac{(x_a - x_b)^2}{4} + 
\left( y - \frac{y_a + y_b}{2} \right)^2 - \frac{(y_a - y_b)^2}{4} = k^2 \\
\left( x - \frac{x_a + x_b}{2} \right)^2 + \left( y - \frac{y_a + y_b}{2} \right)^2 
 = k^2 + \frac{(x_a - x_b)^2}{4} + \frac{(y_a - y_b)^2}{4}
$$

Thus, this is a circumference with a center at the middle of segment $AB$ and its radius. **(This I also failed to understand)**

$$
r = \sqrt{k^2 + \frac{|AB|^2}{4}}
$$

Comment: They seem to have completed the square. Google this, it's a fairly standard procedure from high school algebra.

Comment: @DonAntonio, thank you for the suggestion, I am from the former USSR and in our school this way of a solution of quadratic equations isn't taught. I never heard about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with how to "complete the square?"  To get from

$$
x_a x_b - (x_a+x_b)x + x^2 + y_a y_b - (y_a+y_b)y + y^2 = k^2
$$

to

$$
\left( x - \frac{x_a + x_b}{2} \right)^2 - \frac{(x_a - x_b)^2}{4} + 
\left( y - \frac{y_a + y_b}{2} \right)^2 - \frac{(y_a - y_b)^2}{4} = k^2 \\
$$

consider the following:

$$
\begin{align}
x_ax_b-(x_a+x_b)x+x^2&=x_ax_b-(x_a+x_b)x+x^2+\frac{(x_a - x_b)^2}{4}-\frac{(x_a - x_b)^2}{4}\\
&=\frac{4x_ax_b}{4}-(x_a+x_b)x+x^2+\frac{x_a^2-2x_ax_b+x_b^2}{4}-\frac{(x_a - x_b)^2}{4}\\
&=-(x_a+x_b)x+x^2+\frac{x_a^2+2x_ax_b+x_b^2}{4}-\frac{(x_a - x_b)^2}{4}\\
&=-(x_a+x_b)x+x^2+\frac{(x_a + x_b)^2}{4}-\frac{(x_a - x_b)^2}{4}\\
&=\left( x - \frac{x_a + x_b}{2} \right)^2-\frac{(x_a - x_b)^2}{4}.\\
\end{align}
$$

Similarly,

$$
\begin{align}
y_ay_b-(y_a+y_b)y+y^2&=\left( y - \frac{y_a + y_b}{2} \right)^2-\frac{(y_a - y_b)^2}{4}.\\
\end{align}
$$

As for the second part of your question, the standard equation for a circle with center at $P(h,k)$ and radius $r$ is $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2$.  Therefore,

$$
\left( x - \frac{x_a + x_b}{2} \right)^2 + \left( y - \frac{y_a + y_b}{2} \right)^2 
 = k^2 + \frac{(x_a - x_b)^2}{4} + \frac{(y_a - y_b)^2}{4}
$$

is the equation for the circle with center at $$O\left(\frac{x_a+x_b}{2},\frac{y_a+y_b}{2}\right)$$ and radius

$$\begin{align}
r&=\sqrt{k^2 + \frac{(x_a - x_b)^2}{4} + \frac{(y_a - y_b)^2}{4}}\\
&=\sqrt{k^2 + \frac{|AB|^2}{4}}.
\end{align}
$$

Note that the coordinates of $O$ are the coordinates for the midpoint of segment $AB$.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$x^2\pm a=\left(x\pm\frac{a}{2}\right)^2-\frac{a^2}{4}$$

and this is what they do in the first step, with both $\,x\,,\,y\,$ . For example,

$$y^2-(y_a+y_b)y=\left(y-\frac{y_a+y_b}{2}\right)^2-\frac{(y_a+y_b)^2}{4}\;,\;\;etc.$$

$$|AB|^2=(x_a-x_b)^2+(y_a-y_b)^2\;\ldots$$